# Gap in gate post 4x4

Tags: fence, gap, gate-post

I put up a fence with swinging out gate on downhill driveway. I have a gap between the gate and 4x4. How do i fix gap? I tried cutting 2x4 in a traced pattern of gap.

Comment: Can you provide a few pictures?

Comment: It's very difficult to understand your situation.  How about posting a photo or two?

Comment: A photo would be helpful , it depends on the type of hinges. And the swing.